# How to add DNS server via script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, busybox

How to add DNS server via script if nameserver is not written in **resolv.conf** .
like first check following lines are there or not in resolv.conf file:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

If not then I have to add these lines.
environment is busybox on kelink gateway for LoraWAN

Comment: Honestly, any company, selling a "security gateway" which uses google nameservers, is disqualified. But anyway... Which version of busybox does the box run?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

if ! grep -q '^nameserver 8.8.8.8$' /etc/resolv.conf; then
    echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' >> /etc/resolv.conf
fi
if ! grep -q '^nameserver 8.8.4.4$' /etc/resolv.conf; then
    echo 'nameserver 8.8.4.4' >> /etc/resolv.conf
fi
```